# Titanium Studio login page (Android)

Tags: android, mobile, titanium, cross-platform

I am working on my very first app in Titanium Studio.
So my project consists of an login page and if the login is successful a tableview will populate the screen.

The problem I enconter is, on the Titanium emulator the app works OK, but when I installed on a device, the two textboxs and the button are missing.

Do you have any ideas what I am doing wrong ?

For mobile web, the app works just fine.

Thanks.

The code :

```
var win = Titanium.UI.currentWindow;
var username = Titanium.UI.createTextField({
    color:'#336699',
    top:10,
    left:10,
    width:300,
    height:40,
    hintText:'Username',
    keyboardType:Titanium.UI.KEYBOARD_DEFAULT,
    returnKeyType:Titanium.UI.RETURNKEY_DEFAULT,
    borderStyle:Titanium.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED
});

win.add(username);

var password = Titanium.UI.createTextField({
    color:'#336699',
    top:60,
    left:10,
    width:300,
    height:40,
    hintText:'Password',
    passwordMask:true,
    keyboardType:Titanium.UI.KEYBOARD_DEFAULT,
    returnKeyType:Titanium.UI.RETURNKEY_DEFAULT,
    borderStyle:Titanium.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED
});

win.add(password); 

var loginBtn = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title:'Login',
    top:110,
    width:90,
    height:35,
    borderRadius:1,
    font:{fontFamily:'Arial',fontWeight:'bold',fontSize:14}
});

win.add(loginBtn);
```

Comment: Paste your code, so we could see where is the problem.

Comment: iPhone or Android app? we need to see some code...

Answer (score 0):

for android,

try to remove property [borderStyle](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TextField-property-borderStyle). its for iphone only.

and also comment borderRadius and font property for button and try. If you want to use borderRadius then you need to set other two relative properties for that . borderWidth and borderColor.

to use custom font , you need to first configure it so just try to comment that property and try.